# Cannot install ubuntu 11.04 apps on live usb

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, live-usb

I have ubuntu 11.04 on a 3.6gb usb flash drive. My wifi connection is working fine. But, i cannot install apps via `sudo apt-get install`. It says, failed to fetch repository. I try the software repository app and that says fail too due to some 404 not found error. I am forced to go to the website for the repository and download .deb files and install, windows style.

What is the reason for this ? Maybe i am using an old ubuntu version and the repo is shut ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/a/311010/147044

Comment: 11.04 is ***End Of Life*** and is no longer supported on this site.  Even though this question has an answer, it should be closed as "Offtopic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe i am using an old ubuntu version and the repo is shut ?

That would be correct. 11.04 is an [EOL (End Of Life) Ubuntu release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Unless you want to add the repositories back, use a later version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I would also suggest downloading 13.04 on your computer and using that instead.  Remember to backup your files also so if there is an error you won't lose everything.